# Changing a backgroundImage set via JavaScript using a CSS media query

Tags: javascript, css

I have a responsive menu on my website. In full size, hovering over a button changes the background of the whole menu (not the button!). As I believe that it is impossible to change the background of a div on hovering over one of its child elements via CSS (please correct me if I'm wrong), I do this via JavaScript. For each menu button, I have a function like the following. Each button gives a different background image.

```
function arme() {
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 590) {
        var bild = "url('" + bildliste[3] + "')";
        document.getElementById('auswahlbox').style.backgroundImage=bild;
    }
}
```

As you can see, for lower resolutions (> 590px), the background of the menu does not change because the menu looks different then. The background then is always the same image. CSS looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
    #auswahlbox { background:url(images/koerperbilder/koerperbg.jpg); 
}
```

If I load my website in full size and then make the viewport smaller, the background of the menu changes to the image that is set via CSS. That's how it's supposed to work.

However, now to my problem: If I load my website in full size, hover over a random button (thus activating the JavaScript function above) and *then* make the viewport smaller, the background doesn't change. It stays the way it was set by hovering over the button. Apparently, a backgroundImage that was set via JavaScript beforehand can't be changed back by a simple CSS media query like the one above.

My question is: How can I change a backgroundImage that was set via JavaScript using a CSS media query? And if that is not possible, how can I solve my dilemma?

Right now, this problem is ruining the user experience. Since all other rules of the media query get applied (among them background-position and background-repeat), everything falls apart whenever someone resizes the viewport after hovering over a button. I wonder if someone can help.

Thank you in advance - and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Inline styles take precedence of styles that come from the stylesheet.

Comment: Unless you put `!important` in the stylesheet.

Comment: make your hover apply a class instead of a background style, then you can handle all the backgrounds in CSS, including inside media queries. if done right, size and hover will be independent and the size one could kick-in while hovered.

Answer (score 1):

As you have set backgroundImage property through JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('auswahlbox').style.**backgroundImage**=bild;
```

You should set same property in CSS also. So use following code

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 590px) {
    #auswahlbox { **background-image**:url(images/koerperbilder/koerperbg.jpg); 
}
```